# Hibernate 3 : optimistic locking unit test

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, junit

I'm trying to test my optimistic locking implementation of my application.  However the result is not what I expect.  The steps I take to test are the following

- load an entity from the database
- set the version attribute to one less than present in the database
- change another attribute thats just a string to something else
- save the entity

I expected a staleException now, however the entity just gets saved and the version increases to the next in line.

Here is a small extract of my save code

```
   public <T extends DomainObject> T save(T objectToSave) {
        Session currentSession = null;
        try {
            currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            currentSession.save(objectToSave);
            return objectToSave;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("save error",ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I load objects by id with named queries thru my entire application with following code

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T extends Object> List<T> query(Class<T> returnClass, String query, List<String> namedParams, List<? extends Object> params, Integer limit) {
    Session currentSession = null;
    try {
        currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query namedQuery = currentSession.getNamedQuery(query);
        if(limit != null){
            namedQuery.setMaxResults(limit);
        }
        namedQuery.setCacheable(true);
        if (namedParams != null && namedParams.size() > 0) {
            addParams(namedQuery, namedParams, (List<Object>) params);
        }
        return namedQuery.list();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error("query error",ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

And this is the configuration of my sessionfactory

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="entityInterceptor" ref="auditInterceptor" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.dialect=${hibernate.dialect}
            hibernate.show_sql=${hibernate.show_sql}
            hibernate.cache.provider_class=org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider
            hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory
            hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true
            hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
            hibernate.cache.provider_configuration_file_resource_path=ehcache.xml
            hibernate.generate_statistics=true
            hbm2ddl.auto=${hbm2ddl.auto}
            hibernate.c3p0.min_size=${hibernate.c3p0.min_size}
            hibernate.c3p0.max_size=${hibernate.c3p0.max_size}
            hibernate.c3p0.timeout=${hibernate.c3p0.timeout}
            hibernate.c3p0.max_statements=${hibernate.c3p0.max_statements}
            hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period=${hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period}
        </value>
    </property>
    <property name="schemaUpdate">
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.mbalogos.mba.domain.site.Site</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Is there anything I missed on the configuration of the sessionFactory or do I test it completly wrong and should I test it in a different way ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regressing the version field is dangerous as it is Hibernate controlled (if you're using the JPA versioning functionality). Load in an entity, detach it (maybe use session.evict(obj)), alter an attribute. Load in the same entity, keep it attached, alter it, save it. Reattach the first entity and attempt to save it (I think Merge will do this). You should then see the StaleObjectStateException exception.

Comment: Hey, I'm using the import javax.persistence.Version; annotation so indeed JPA versioning.  But when you say detach do you mean leave the transaction with it or something else ?  I simplified my question tbh cause the entire story is a bit more complex.  I'm using a REST service that loads a domainobject fe: Site with version 1.  Then I transform from domainobject to Json value object and send it thru spring mvc to the client.  There the changes happen to the json object.  It gets send back REST style to the service together with the id of the site.

Comment: I load the site from database copy all properties from the new jsonobject to the loaded site object, and then save the site.  I hope this is clear ?  It's kinda complex to explain in text.

Comment: You're effectively using JSON to create DTOs. Is the version attribute being set correctly in the DTO and deserialized properly when you save? You should make two genuine updates from the same versioned DTO rather than trying to regress the version number. i.e. make two calls to get the DTOs (both the same version), make a change, update the first DTO over your RESTful interface, then update the second DTO, attempt to save it. This should fire the exception, if it doesn't you possibly have a defect somewhere.

Comment: I've rewritten the test like you describe now.  It's an intigration test that launches a war running my webservice, and with Spring RestTemplate I perform my calls.  Now I call a site/1 twice, then update the seocnd site, save it.  Then update my first site, save it, and my test still passes.  I checked the version field in the jsonobjects and they where both at 1.  Just to be sure I called a get again after the first save and it returned 2.  But after saving the second and fething it, it was at 3 instead of my stale exception.  I'm trying to determine if I can put a debug point somewhere now

Comment: I beleive I found it, it's my own fault.  The first thing I do when I update my domainobjects is   Contact contactToStore = contactRepository.loadContactById(id);
  MbaBeanUtils.mbaCopyProperties(contact, contactToStore);  I'm fetching the current contact from the database ofcourse I will have the latest save then ...  I'm totally throwing away the optimistic locking.  Thnx for the responses your insights brought me closer to finding my own stupid mistake

Comment: No problems. All the related articles do show that you have to merge into a new object rather than loading by ID as if you do this, updates to Version are thrown away by Hibernate.