# Hibernate optimistic locking test

Tags: java, hibernate, testing

I know this has been asked before, but I'm trying to test Hibernate's optimistic locking feature using a version field.

I've seen the following answer which outlines how to test this [Hibernate 3 : optimistic locking unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045579/hibernate-3-optimistic-locking-unit-test/13045637#13045637).

Can someone confirm whether or not my test is doing this correctly as I'm not getting the StaleObjectStateException that I'm expecting to see.

```
@Test(expected = StaleObjectStateException.class)
public void optimisticLockingTest() {
    DummyEntity entity= new DummyEntity("name");
    entityDao.persist(entity);

    entityDao.detach(entity);
    entity.setName("new name");

    // Get new instance of the same entity
    final DummyEntity newEntity = entityDao.findById(entity.getId());
    newEntity.setName("Different name");
    entityDao.persist(newEntity);

    entity = entityDao.merge(entity );
    entityDao.persist(entity);
}
```

Comment: It just calls entityManager.detach(entity). Where entityManager is annotated with @PersistenceContext

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version is incremented just before the update to the database happens.

As all this code is in one transaction, when you do `entityDao.findById(entity.getId());` the `entity.getVersion()` would still be 0 so both entity and newEntity will have same Id and same Version.

You need to force the update to the database after each `persist()` and `merge()` with either `EntityManager.flush()` or by programmatically start/commit transactions.

So the code would be:

```java
    DummyEntity entity= new DummyEntity("name");
    entityDao.persist(entity);
    entityDao.flush();
    entityDao.detach(entity);

    final DummyEntity newEntity = entityDao.findById(entity.getId());
    newEntity.setName("Different name");
    entityDao.persist(newEntity);
    entityDao.flush();

    entity.setName("new name");
    entity = entityDao.merge(entity );
    entityDao.persist(entity);
```